# Fixed-width sidebar with responsive content column in Foundation 5?

Tags: zurb-foundation, fixed, sidebar

I've been using Foundation since v3 and so I hadn't expected this kind of snafu.

In this particular case I need a fixed-width left column (large-3) then a fluid/responsive content column (large-9) for the remainder.

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="large-3 columns" id="sidebar" style="width: 300px">
    sidebar
    </div>

    <div class="large-9 columns" id="content">
    content
    </div>

</div>
```

Problem is, when scaling down, the content column is wrapping/being forced down below the sidebar (even before the next screen-width threshold is crossed). I tried "fixed" and "sticky" classes in the `#sidebar` but they don't seem to affect this behavior.

I didn't want to start hacking the CSS if there was an existing (Foundation?) solution.

Answer (score 7):

Much like @naota's approach, the response I got from Zurb was to hack the css. Set an absolutely-positioned, fixed-width sidebar, then create a new div with left-padding: 300px;

Something like:

```
<div class="row">

    <div id="sidebar" style="position: absolute; width: 300px;">
    </div>

    <div class="large-12 columns" id="content" style="padding-left: 300px">
    </div>

</div>
```

It works surprisingly well...for a hack.

Comment: This is not bad, but if the page is very wide, then there's extra padding on the content... [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/xn5ccp0r/1/). Any idea how to fix? I placed the div outside of the row since in the row it was not clickable, and it stuck to the row left edge instead of the page left edge anyway.

Comment: I don't recall having this problem but then it's been awhile since I did all this. Perhaps convert the 300px to a relative percentage on both? Otherwise I'd just try to right-align/float the sidebar content div so it was always up against the right column (or vice versa).

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I use with SASS to create fixed column widths.

### Code

```
@mixin fixed($width, $direction) {
  position: absolute;
  width: rem-calc($width) + $column-gutter;
  top: 0;
  @if $direction == left {
    left: 0;
  } @else {
    right: 0;
  }
}
@mixin fluid($width, $direction) {
  @if $direction == left {
    padding-right: rem-calc($width) + ($column-gutter * 1.5);
  } @else {
    padding-left: rem-calc($width) + ($column-gutter * 1.5);
  }
}
```

### Using the code

To insert a fixed, 300px, right column, add `@include fixed(300, right);` to the right column class, and `@include fluid(300, left);` to the left column class. *Do not mix with the default `small-# column` classes.*

### Extending the code

If you'd like to setup permanent classes, similarly to `small-3 column`, `large-6 column`, etc, just add the following code. You will now be able to use `large-fluid-300-left` for the left fluid column and `large-fixed-300-right` for the right fixed column.

```
// Fixed 300px
.row { position: relative; }
@media #{$small-up} {
  .small-fixed-300-left.column { @include fixed(300, left); }
  .small-fixed-300-right.column { @include fixed(300, right); }
  .small-fluid-300-left.column { @include fluid(300, left); }
  .small-fluid-300-right.column { @include fluid(300, right); }
}
@media #{$medium-up} {
  .medium-fixed-300-left.column { @include fixed(300, left); }
  .medium-fixed-300-right.column { @include fixed(300, right); }
  .medium-fluid-300-left.column { @include fluid(300, left); }
  .medium-fluid-300-right.column { @include fluid(300, right); }
}
@media #{$large-up} {
  .large-fixed-300-left.column { @include fixed(300, left); }
  .large-fixed-300-right.column { @include fixed(300, right); }
  .large-fluid-300-left.column { @include fluid(300, left); }
  .large-fluid-300-right.column { @include fluid(300, right); }
}
```

## Bonus - Set Minimum Widths

If you're working with Ads, you'll likely come across a point, where you'll need the column to collapse into its own row, once it reaches a certain minimum width. Here's what I use to set minimum column widths.

### Code

```
@mixin min($width) {
  width: $width + px;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  + .column {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

### Using the code

Add `@include min(300);` to a column class. *Must be used in addition to the `column` class.*

### Extending the code

The following code allows you to add classes, such as `.small-min-300.column` to columns which you wish to collapse, if they are every squeezed below 300px.

```
// Min 300px
@media #{$small-up} {
  .small-min-300.column { @include min(300); }
}
@media #{$medium-up} {
  .medium-min-300.column { @include min(300); }
}
@media #{$large-up} {
  .large-min-300.column { @include min(300); }
}
```

I've pulled this directly from my SASS file and haven't tested the code at the time of writing. Let me know if something doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Anyone try this with the new Foundation flex grid?

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar issue. The code below uses `display:table` to wrap your code into two parts.

**CSS**:

```
<style type="text/css">
.wrapper_table{
    display: table;
    width:100%;
}
.wrapper_row{
    display:table-row;
    vertical-align:top;
 }
.wrapper_cell{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
}
</style>
```

**HTML**:

```
<section class="wrapper_table">
    <div class="wrapper_row">
        <div class="wrapper_cell">
            <!-- your side bar is here -->
            <div class="columns" id="sidebar" style="width:300px;">
            sidebar
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper_cell">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- your content is here -->
                <div class="large-12 columns" id="content" >
                    content content content content content
                    content content content content content 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</section>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would add this to what you have:
https://gist.github.com/cavneb/94efadc92574d61dc3f7

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone found this old article recently trying to find a way to have a fixed-width column in Foundation, I was able to do this with Foundation 6.  I'm using the Flex-Grid, and there is a wonderful class called `.shrink`.  Shrink will make the column only as wide as it's contents, so you can have an element in there like a nav item or image, and the column will stay that width as other column around it take up the remaining space.  I was able to do a fixed-width center column thusly:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="columns"></div>
  <div class="shrink columns">
    This will shrink to it's contents - set a width on something here!
  </div>
  <div class="columns"></div>
</div>
```

Official Foundation doc page for the `.shrink` class:
https://codepen.io/ZURBFoundation/pen/aWYVgd